# python: inserting row at specifc index from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a two dataframes as follows:

df1:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   8   6   4   9   7
1   2   6   3   8   5
2   0   7   6   5   8
```

df2:

```
    M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3   8   6   5
4   5   4   3
```

I have taken out a slice of data from `df1` as follows:

```
>data_1 = df1.loc[0:1]
>data_1
    A   B   C   D   E
0   8   6   4   9   7
1   2   6   3   8   5
```

Now I need to insert this `data_1` into `df2` at specific location of `Index(0,P)` (row,column). Is there any way to do it? I do not want to disturb the other columns in `df2`.

I can extract individual values of each cell and do it but since I have to do it for a large dataset, its not possible to do it cell-wise.

Cellwise method:

```
>var1 = df1.iat[0,1]
>var2 = df1.iat[0,0]

>df2.at[0, 'P'] = var1
>df2.at[0, 'Q'] = var2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename columns and index names for match to second `DataFrame`, so possible use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) for correct way specifiest by tuple `pos`:

```
data_1 = df1.loc[0:1]
print (data_1)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  8  6  4  9  7
1  2  6  3  8  5

pos = (2, 'P')
data_1 = data_1.rename(columns=dict(zip(data_1.columns, df2.loc[:, pos[1]:].columns)),
                       index=dict(zip(data_1.index, df2.loc[pos[0]:].index)))
print (data_1)
   P  Q  R  S  T
2  8  6  4  9  7
3  2  6  3  8  5

df2.update(data_1)
print (df2)
   M  N  O    P    Q    R    S    T
0  1  2  3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  4  5  6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  7  8  9  8.0  6.0  4.0  9.0  7.0
3  8  6  5  2.0  6.0  3.0  8.0  5.0
4  5  4  3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

How working `rename` - idea is select all columns and all index values after specified column, index name by `loc` and then zip by columns names of `data_1` with convert to dictionary. So last replace bot, index and columns names in `data_1` by next columns, index values.

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. Could you please elaborate more on the ```data_1.rename``` code?

Answer (score 2):

If you specify all the columns, it is possible to do it as follows:

```
df2.loc[0:1, ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T']] = df1.loc[0:1].values
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
    M   N   O     P    Q    R    S    T
0   1   2   3   8.0  6.0  4.0  9.0  7.0
1   4   5   6   2.0  6.0  3.0  8.0  5.0
2   7   8   9
3   8   6   5
4   5   4   3
```